# Two apps vs one app

Tags: design, architecture, programming-practices, mobile

We are developing a mobile app/apps which has two parties involved, creators and consumers. Creators first register themselves, get verified and then create the events. Consumers browse for desired events and if found interesting, register for the event.

What will be the best practice to achieve the above scenario. Two different app with separate set of relevant features for creators and consumers or a single app which say first open in consumer mode and provide an option to switch to creator mode.

Edit:

- No major feature is common between consumers and creators. Only things like signup/login, consumers can see the events in their locality whereas creators can see the events created by them will be common.
- Creators and Consumers are always different set of people. Creators will never consume and Consumers will never create.

Comment: Are there features hat should be available to both consumers and creators? If so, how many?

Comment: @marstato There will be barely any common feature. Some common things will be like both will need login/Signup page,  Consumers can see all the events in their locality similarly Producers can see all the events created by them.

Comment: Are you going to create two different sites for creators and consumers? Are you going to target both sides through totally different channels? If it's the same logical property, creating separate apps might be confusing for your users. Whichever category they match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there are no common features i suggest creating separate applications. That lets you update either app without confusing your users (e.g. updating an app without changing anything for the consumers).

Merging the two apps at a later point is probably easier than tearing one in half.

Comment: Properly factoring out the few common modules (e.g. authentication/authorization) into re-usable components should take care of any potential code duplication left.

Comment: I just thought: if it was only for the separate Updates one could create configurable app and deploy two artifacts with fixed configurations: one for consumers, one for creators....

Answer (score 3):

Will creators never consume?   Will consumers never create?  If you can answer yes to both, then I would consider two applications.  If not, then I would consider one application.

This seems similar to email.  Reading is a consumption function, while write is a creator function.  I haven't seen many useful applications that don't provide both functionalities, even though the requirements are significantly different.  There are automated consumers and producers, but they are a limited subset.

Comment: Creators and consumers are always different set of people. So, creators never consume and consumers never create.